# Create Hello World with RESTful web service and Jersey

Tags: jakarta-ee, rest, jaxb, jersey, netbeans6.8

I follow tutorial  [here](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/gipzz.html)  on how to create web service using RESTful web service and Jersey and I get kind of stuck. The code is from HelloWorld3 in the tutorial I linked above. Here is the code. I use Netbean6.8 + glassfish v3

`RESTGreeting.java` create using `JAXB`. This class represents the HTML message in Java

```
package com.sun.rest;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;


@XmlRootElement(name = "restgreeting")
public class RESTGreeting {
private String message;
private String name;

/**
 * Creates new instance of Greeting
 */
public RESTGreeting() {
}

/* Create new instance of Greeting
 * with parameters message and name
 */
public RESTGreeting(
    String message,
    String name) {
    this.message = message;
    this.name = name;
}

/** Getter for message
 * return value for message
 *
 */
@XmlElement
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

/* Getter for name
 * return name
 */
@XmlElement
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

`HelloGreetingService.java` creates a RESTful web service that returns an HTML message

```
package com.sun.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;


@Path("helloGreeting")
public class HelloGreetingService {
@Context
private UriInfo context;

/** Creates a new instance of HelloGreetingService */
public HelloGreetingService() {
}

/**
 * Retrieves representation of an instance of com.sun.rest.HelloGreetingService
 * @return an instance of java.lang.String
 */
@GET
@Produces("text/html")
public RESTGreeting getHtml(@QueryParam("name")
String name) {
    return new RESTGreeting(
        getGreeting(),
        name);
}

private String getGreeting() {
    return "Hello ";
}

/**
 * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of HelloGreetingService
 * @param content representation for the resource
 * @return an HTTP response with content of the updated or created resource.
 */
@PUT
@Consumes("text/html")
public void putHtml(String content) {
}
}
```

However when i deploy it on Glassfish, and run it. It generate an exception. I try to debug using netbean 6.8, and figure out that this line `return new RESTGreeting(getGreeting(), name);` in `HelloGreetingService.java` cause the exception. But not sure why. Here is the stacktrace

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:268)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1029)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:941)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:932)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:384)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:451)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:632)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your resource method returns an instance of a JAXB-annotated class and will not be able to produce HTML (the example returns HTML in an ordinary java String). Isn't it XML you want? In that case change the annotation on getHtml to

@Produces({"application/xml"})

Comment: tyvm, that fix it, but if I want to html so that I can display on the web browser, can I convert JAXB into string somehow?

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of. However, Jersey supports page rendering using JSP (http://blogs.sun.com/sandoz/entry/mvcj) but it won't use your JAXB annotations for that.

Is it a regular web application you're building or a web service?

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse

http://www.brucephillips.name/blog/index.cfm/2009/5/28/An-Introduction-to-Creating-RESTful-Web-Services-Using-Jersey-and-Java#comments

If you are not using maven then place the jars mentioned in WEB-INF/lib folder if lib folder is not preset create one an place the jars.

Also make sure the jar version is same as mentioned in the document or else it gives error.

Download the zip file if you dont want to create the application that works great.
If you want the JAR files contact me.