# How to publish "Hello world" Rest web service?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, connectexception

```
package my.first.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("hello")
public class Hello {

  // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is requested
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayHelloInPlainText() {       
    return "Hello world!";
  }
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893796/create-hello-world-with-restful-web-service-and-jersey
  // This method is called if HTML is requested
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHelloInHtml() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello world!" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello world!" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }
}
```

This is my code I wrote web service Restful.  When I publish with Test Client Then this error is coming:

```
IWAB0489E Error when deploying Web service to Axis runtime
  axis-admin failed with  {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}
  Server.userException java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

How will I fix it?  This is coming with Rest only, not with SOAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download the jersey [implementation of REST from sunmicrosystem] and include those jars in your application apart from this you have to modify your web.xml accordingly.

There are multiple beginners tutorial available on net - [click here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html)

Comment: naveen Thanx  its working now But i have some more QUery will please helpp me can i have ur email id so that i can ask some small small Question in webservice

Comment: http://localhost:8080/HelloRestefullClient/sampleHelloProxy/TestClient.jsp  this is my http://localhost:8080/HelloRestefullClient/sampleHelloProxy/TestClient.jsp  url to Test client how i will make URl so that i can Use in another application

Comment: Hi, Jersey has the client library using that you could invoke your REST service, Apart from this you can invoke your REST service via any other http client like java HttpUrlConnection or apache Http Client.

Comment: can u please Explain how i will find the URL from That i can access this Service another Pc which connected to My server

Comment: What is use of wsdl In webService ?

Comment: Here you are using REST based service, WSDL is used when you write SOAP based webservice. WSDL is a file that contains information of your deployed webservice [ about webservice endpoint, all operations and input/output message structure of respective operations] <br> For your REST service you can find the servie path using the PATH annotation. if you hit a get url like http://{servername}:{port}/{application_name}/hello , It will land to your say hello function, for more read about Path annotation

Comment: So There is no Relation with rest to wsdl or uddi, ?one more thing i want to know why we make client of web service  what the use  of that when test the client one Project automatic come in workspace so i want to know what is use of that ?

Comment: 1 - REST has different kind of document WADL instead of WSDL, So the WSDL not belongs to REST but WADL<br>2 - We create the client to consume the webservices. Exposing the webservice and consuming the webservice both are different thing.

Comment: Yes i want to Know about Relation between UDDI,WSDL,SOAP WEBSERVICE CAN please explain it ?

Comment: I will suggest you to go through http://www.w3schools.com , it is very good tutorial to start learning.